# Why is this UIImageView autocentering itself?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView in a UIScrollView in another UIScrollView (based on Apple's 
[PhotoScroller sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/)). When the UIScrollView calls back to its controller to dismiss itself, it calls this method:

```
- (void)dismiss {
    [scrollView removeFromSuperview];
    ImageScrollView *isv = [self currentImageScrollView];
    UIImage *image = isv.imageView;
    image.frame = [self.view convertRect:image.frame fromView:isv];

    [self.view insertSubview:image belowSubview:captionView];
    [(NSObject *)delegate performSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidClose:)
                               withObject:self
                               afterDelay:2.0];
}
```

Now here's the weird part: the image view jumps to a different position right after this method executes, but before the `scollViewDidClose` method gets called on the delegate. If the image is larger than its new super view, it jumps so that its left edge is aligned with the left edge of its super view. If it's smaller than its new super view, it jumps to the very center of the view. There is no animation to this change.

So my question is, how do I prevent it from doing that? I've tweaked both the super view (`self.view`) class and the image view class to see what methods might be called. Neither the frame nor the center is set on the image view after this method is called, and while the `layoutSubviews` method is called on the super view, that is *not* what jumps the image to the center or left side of the superview. I've also tried turning off `autoResizesSubviews` in the super view, and setting the `autoresizingMask` of the image view to `UIViewAutoresizingNone`, with no change in behavior.

So where is this happening, and why? And more importantly, how do I make it stop?

I've been beating my head on this for days. Any pointers or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't posted the correct code.  UIScrollView does not have an imageView property, and UIImage does not have a frame property.

Comment: Darren—I'm using a subclass of UIScrollView, based on Apple's [PhotoScroller example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller), which has an `imageView` ivar for which I've simply added an accessor.

Comment: I've changed the class to `ImageScrollView`, which is the subclass with the `imageView` property. Thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageScrollView` is the one centering your UIImageView.  Set a breakpoint in `ImageScrollView layoutSubviews` and you'll see how your UIImageView is being centered.

You're taking `ImageScrollView`'s internal `imageView` and placing it into another view.  That's not going to work because `ImageScrollView` still retains ownership of that `UIImageView` instance and is still managing its layout.

You'll either need to copy the image into another `UIImageView` instance, or you'll need to change `ImageScrollView` to allow it to relinquish ownership of its `imageView`.

Comment: I've tried setting a flag on the `ImageScrollView` so that `layoutSubviews` returns without doing anything in my `UIScrollView` subclass. It has no effect; the image still gets centered. Furthermore, in my example code, the UIScrollView that contains the ImageScrollView is removed from its superview. So in fact, `layoutSubviews` is not called at all -- at least not after my `-dismiss` method finishes executing. I'll fool with it some more, but I'm pretty sure that `layoutSubviews` is not the culprit here -- er, unless it's the parent UIScrollView that's the cause. Will have to check that next.

Comment: Just fiddled, no joy. :-( Note that `scrollView` is removed from its super view. That prevents `layoutSubviews` from being called in either the `scrollView` `UIScrollView` or the `ImageScrollView`, or at least they're not called after this code executes. I did notice, however, that the image is getting horizontally only, not vertically. Hrm. Might it be that the code to center is getting called *before* my `dismiss` method, but its effects are taking place afterward? So confused by this…

Comment: Okay, just went at this again and cleaned things up and discovered that you're exactly right, Darren. Man oh *man* am I glad to finally have this issue licked. Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oh, BTW, key to getting it to work was removing the line `    [scrollView removeFromSuperview];`. For some bizarre reason, with that in, it continues to do the centering. I don't get it, but am happy to have the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting up the frame of the 'image' view when you insert it as a subview. You probably want to do that explicitly if you want the view to appear at a particular position in the scroll view.

Comment: Thanks, that seems obvious, doesn't it? I was afraid I'd make the example too simple. Unfortunately, I have in fact been setting the frame all *kinds* of ways in this code. It goes wherever I put it, but still immediately shifts to the center of its new super view once this method finishes execution. I've updated the example code to reflect this sad state of affairs.